# Nestjs Mirko-orm through exception with no trace

Tags: nestjs, mikro-orm, nestjs-config

Im stuck trying to identify where this error is in my nestjs application. Anyone have any ideas or options I can add to get more info?

```
    [Nest] 8792  - 06/10/2023, 3:32:29 pm   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'values')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'values')
    at ./api\services\node-app\node_modules\@nestjs-plus\discovery\src\discovery.service.ts:68:50     
    at arrayMap (./api\services\node-app\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:653:23)
    at map (./api\services\node-app\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:9622:14)
    at Function.flatMap (./api\services\node-app\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:9325:26)
    at new DiscoveryService (./api\services\node-app\node_modules\@nestjs-plus\discovery\src\discovery.service.ts:67:7)
    at Injector.instantiateClass (./api\services\node-app\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:365:19)
    at callback (./api\services\node-app\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:65:45)        
    at Injector.resolveConstructorParams (./api\services\node-app\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:144:24)
    at Injector.loadInstance (./api\services\node-app\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:70:13)
    at Injector.loadProvider (./api\services\node-app\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:97:9)
    at Injector.lookupComponentInImports (./api\services\node-app\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:289:17)
    at Injector.lookupComponentInParentModules (./api\services\node-app\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:252:33)
    at Injector.resolveComponentInstance (./api\services\node-app\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:207:33)
    at resolveParam (./api\services\node-app\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:128:38)   
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at Injector.resolveConstructorParams (./api\services\node-app\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:143:27)
    at Injector.loadInstance (./api\services\node-app\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:70:13)
    at Injector.loadProvider (./api\services\node-app\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:97:9)
    at ./api\services\node-app\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\instance-loader.js:56:13
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at InstanceLoader.createInstancesOfProviders (./api\services\node-app\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\instance-loader.js:55:9)
    at ./api\services\node-app\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\instance-loader.js:40:13
    at async Promise.all (index 33)
    at InstanceLoader.createInstances (./api\services\node-app\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\instance-loader.js:39:9)
    at InstanceLoader.createInstancesOfDependencies (./api\services\node-app\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\instance-loader.js:22:13)
    at ./api\services\node-app\node_modules\@nestjs\core\nest-factory.js:108:17
    at Function.asyncRun (./api\services\node-app\node_modules\@nestjs\core\errors\exceptions-zone.js:22:13)
    at NestFactoryStatic.initialize (./api\services\node-app\node_modules\@nestjs\core\nest-factory.js:106:13)
    at NestFactoryStatic.create (./api\services\node-app\node_modules\@nestjs\core\nest-factory.js:42:9)
```

I have tried NEST_DEBUG=1, which just shows this error being thrown once "LOG [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +3ms"

Comment: Looks like an error in the `@nestjs-plus/discovery` package that is probably using an `onModuleInit` that Nest is calling. Hard to say why without knowing what it's looking for. You could try to manually modify that `node_modules` to add some extra debugging and figure out what is happening